# Cartridge faucet leaks, fixed but only lasts a few days

Tags: bathroom, faucet, cartridge

I keep buying new faucet cartridges for my house.  For a few days there is no more leak but within a month it starts leaking again.  It does not seem to matter what make or model.  I love the old style compression faucets where you turn the knob and its off and no drip... but hard to find these types now.

Comment: Maybe it is not the cartridge?  There probably is other damage that needs to be fixed first.  Maybe a seat needs refacing.  A picture/name of the faucet might help.  A cartridge not right for the faucet, I expect to leak.

Comment: As I said it does not seem to matter what make or model.  I buy the right kind.  Its fine for a few days but no more.  These are relatively new faucets, no damage.

Comment: I also tried cleaning with vinegar.  That helps but only for a few days.

Comment: There is something else wrong than just the cartridge.  Either damage you do not see, or you are putting the cartridge in wrong.  I am betting on the first, but would not put money on it.  A cartridge should last for years, but wear/tears/nicks/bad seat will give you the few days you get.  Take the cartridge out and carefully examine where it goes.  Everything should be be smooth.  Might need something with zoom to look for defects.

Comment: ok then why does cleaning with vinegar work then?  (for about  same amount of time as a new one).

Comment: Do you have pictures? Words are great... but a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: If cleaning (inside) with vinegar helps, you may have hard water buildup. Do you know your water quality, have you had it tested? Have you had problems with flow rate or blockage in any other fixtures?

Comment: I know I said bathroom... but the kitchen faucet was leaking the worst so checked out that one.  The kitchen faucet had a lot of salt deposits.  I cleaned out with vinegar and stopped leaking for now.  No problems with flow rate or blockage.  Not sure of water quality... in Northern NJ US if that narrows it down. [link](https://sillycycle.com/images/kitchen_housing.jpg)  [link](https://sillycycle.com/images/kitchen_cartridge.jpg)  (Pictures taken before cleaning, looks sparkling new after cleaning.)  Hansgrohe faucet... not picking on them though they all have same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your symptoms are synonymous with water issues.

It may be minerals or other particulate in the water.  These particulates may have damaged parts of the faucets the cartridges seal against.  New cartridges will seal for awhile, but then become gradually damaged and your leak is back.

You may want to consider having your water tested and then purchasing an appropriate whole home water filter.  They can be something other than large expensive units. A [filter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GUQDSBG) such as a sediment filter could be all you need.

After that you will have to consider replacing faucets.

Comment: Not sure which would help a water softener or sediment water filter.  But it seems to me what is not working is the cartridge faucets.   The old style washer compression faucets don't give me trouble.

Comment: @ Dave, A water softener will not remove  damaging particulate.  But a filter will not soften the water.  The compression style is working because of...well compression, where as the cartridges rely more on a slide open slide close type of seal.